# Which files in new folder are to be added by git

Tags: git

In my project I've created a new folder and many files inside it, not all of which should be 'added', 'committed' by git and 'pushed' to the remote.

`git status` just tells me that the entire folder is new and must be added but how do I see which files inside are actually being added.

I've added some things to the `.gitignore` but I want to verify I didn't miss anything.

Comment: You're providing conflicting info. Did you commit new folder? What is the output of git status?

Comment: It just lists the the folder. But I wanted to know if I add the folder, which of its files will be tracked and which ignored.

Comment: @romellem indeed it's the same problem. It's duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`git add` just of the files inside the folder and then `git status` will list all the other files in the folder that are untracked.

```
git add myFolder/file1.txt
git status
```

But not sure how one would do this recursively if there were folders in folders.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that for a directory that contains only untracked files, only the directory name is shown by `status`.  But at that point, nothing has been added, so it doesn't really matter.

Once you do a `git add` (but before you commit) you can do `git status` again, and you will see which individual files are staged.  If you've set up the `gitignore` the way you intend (and if you don't use the force option when you `add`) then it should be just the files you want committed.

If you find that a file was added by mistake, you can unstage it

```
git rm --cached path/to/unwanted/file
```

and then, presumably, update your ignore rules.